# Setting an Int value, not reference or pointer

Tags: c#, int

In C# how do you set an int to a value, not a reference?

I currently am in a foreach loop.

```
int prev = 0;

foreach(Activity a in activities)
{
 //----
 Do something
 //----

 prev = a.number
}
```

The problem is prev is only referencing so every time it goes to the next activity it changes. I need it to be set not referenced.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you explain what do you want to achieve and what do you get? I don't understand your problem.

Comment: You're setting the value of `prev` on every iteration so unless `a.number` is a constant value, then it will get a new value every time you go through the loop. Please explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Int is a value type so you're always setting value not reference.

Comment: Agreed. As it is, `prev` will change because you're changing it in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a reference if you just use out keyword unless it just passes the values.
in this case prev updates cause each time you overwrite existing value with the new value.
that's why the value inside pre changes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Boxing and UnBoxing of .Net?

Refer to the link below

[Boxing and Unboxing (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx)